# What is the effect of adding a variable type binding in signature in SML on the Module?

Tags: sml, smlnj

In the following code:

```
signature DIGIT = 
sig
  type digit
  val make_digit : int -> digit
  val increment : digit -> digit
  val decrement : digit -> digit
  val down_and_up : digit -> digit
  val test : digit -> unit
end

structure Digit :> DIGIT =
struct
  type digit = int
  exception BadDigit
  exception FailTest
  fun make_digit i = if i < 0 orelse i > 9 then raise BadDigit else i
  fun increment d = if d=9 then 0 else d+1
  fun decrement d = if d=0 then 9 else d-1
  val down_and_up = increment o decrement (* recall o is composition *)
  fun test d = if down_and_up d = d then () else raise FailTest
end
```

I run `Digit.test 10;` in SML compiler  for two different cases, of the line `type digit` in the aforementioned code:

1. In case of `type digit` :

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree [overload conflict]
  operator domain: Digit.digit
  operand:         [int ty]
```

2. In case of `type digit = int`: `uncaught exception FailTest`

My question is simply, what difference does it make when we inserted `= int` so that the output/error is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is a type error because you haven't specified what the `digit` type is in this structure.

The second raises an exception as a runtime error because `increment (decrement 10)` is 0.

(I would consider it a design problem that you can use any of the functions with any `int`, not just things that have been validated by `make_digit`.)